# Get number of commas in a line using Vimscript

Tags: vimscript

This question may have an obvious answer that I'm missing, but how can I easily tell how many of a character, in this case " , " are in a line, or a specified string using vimscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VimScript does not have a special character type. In fact, you always `count()` for substrings (or items in list):

```
:echo count(getline("."), ",")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

`:echo len(split(getline('.'), ','))`

That will get the content of the current line, split it on the `,` (comma) to a list and count the number of items of the list.

Note: that the `count()` function just relatively recently learned about counting items in strings, while this solution is also compatible with Vim 7.

Comment: Should be `len(split(getline('.'), ",", 1)) - 1` as split produces more items than separators, and also to count commas at the start and the end of the line.